# RefTex searching for multiple articles with Helm

Tags: helm, auctex, latex, reftex-mode

I recently started using Helm and am really enjoying it. However, I use emacs to write a lot of LaTeX. When I cite articles, I often need to cite several in the same cite macro - I could search my bibliography file for two separate entries very easily, using RefTex:

```
citekey1\|citekey2
```

However when helm mode is on, this no longer works. I can still search for single articles but not multiple articles. How can I do the above in helm?

Comment: I like Helm as well, but switched back to `reftex-citation` for bibtex keys for exactly this reason!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tyler suggested that Helm could be simply disabled for `reftex-citation`. After a bit of digging, I found that this can be done by modifying the `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist` variable. I would recommend reading the documentation on it (using `C-h v helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`), but adding this line to you `init.el` file will do the trick:

```
(eval-after-load 'helm-mode '(add-to-list 
    'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(reftex-citation . nil) )
    )
```

With this line included, `reftex-citation` should run without deferring to `helm`.

Comment: That is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with [`helm-bibtex`](https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex), available through MELPA or GitHub.

Just use `C-SPC` to select entries and then `TAB` and "insert citation".